SSH session over ipv6 hangs after short time, works fine over ipv4
I have set up a server and a router (two machines) with both ipv4 and ipv6 (ULA).
Ubuntu Version: 24.04.
When using ipv4 for both ssh and cockpit everything works fine.
When using ipv6 following happens:

when connecting to ssh, i get a session, but after typing ~5 letters in the terminal, the session hangs. After a long time it can recover, but hangs again after typing a few chars
unable to login to cockpit. The login page displays, but is very slow to display in the browser)

Even though I'm testing it on Ubuntu server 24.04, same thing happens with Ubuntu server 22.04.4 and fedora Server 40.
ssh client log (aaa i started typing just to put some chars into the session, after which it got stuck):
debug3: obfuscate_keystroke_timing: starting: interval ~20ms
aaaadebug3: obfuscate_keystroke_timing: stopping: chaff time expired (162 chaff packets sent)

<manually issuing logout after long recovery by pressing ctrl-d>

logout
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 [session] r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

debug3: obfuscate_keystroke_timing: stopping: no active channels (0 chaff packets sent)
debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to router closed.
Transferred: sent 9636, received 11784 bytes, in 444.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 21.7, received 26.5
debug1: Exit status 130


cockpit log
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit-wsinstance-http.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service http instance...
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance factory...
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Listening on cockpit-wsinstance-http.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service http instance.
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Listening on cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance factory.
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit.service - Cockpit Web Service...
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Started cockpit.service - Cockpit Web Service.
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Started cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory@5-4594-110.service - Cockpit Web Service https instance factory (PID 4594/UID 110).
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit-wsinstance-https@e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855...
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Listening on cockpit-wsinstance-https@e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Started cockpit-wsinstance-https@e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.service - Cockpit Web Service https instance e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory@5-4594-110.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan cockpit-session[4607]: pam_ssh_add: Failed adding some keys
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan cockpit-session[4607]: pam_unix(cockpit:session): session opened for user x(uid=1000) by x(uid=0)
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan systemd-logind[745]: New session 82 of user x.
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan systemd[1]: Started session-82.scope - Session 82 of User x.
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan cockpit-session[4607]: pam_unix(cockpit:session): session closed for user x
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan systemd[1]: session-82.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan systemd-logind[745]: Session 82 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan systemd-logind[745]: Removed session 82.

Dump from tcpdump -i eno1 ip6 can be found here
Does anyone know what could cause this and how to debug it?

Please do a packet capture while reproducing the problem, to check for possible problems at the IP or link layer.  tcpdump -w  and review with Wireshark for example.
